# How to get started with graphics programming?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm a programming noob with;
(a) Basic C++ skills and
(b) Fair skills in computational programming (though that might not be of great help).
I want to generate the Utah teapot for which I have the data set. I have read the NeHe tutorials, but I really want to get my hands dirty. So could you please tell me how to use OpenGL with Dev C++. I know Visual C++ (suggested by NeHe) is far more convenient, however, as I have mentioned earlier, I want to rough it a bit.
Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Comment: I would like to suggest to not use Dev C++. There is no good reason to use it over Visual Studio. And what's more, it's no longer actively developed (and hasn't been for years) and fairly old.

Comment: Please use Visual Studio / Visual C++. Dev-C++ is so outdated and overused it's not even funny. If you're looking for a free alternative use Code::Blocks, it's miles better than Dev-C++

Comment: Dev-C++ is just a wrapper around GCC and GNU Make, both of which *are* still supported and actively developed. You could take a look at those if you want.

Comment: If you really want to practice your skills, develop a Snake-like game using OpenGL. That's fun!

Answer (score 2):

Are you having issues with getting your hands dirty, or having issues with using OpenGL with Dev C++?

If you want to learn OpenGL quickly (get your hands dirty) then simply pick a simple project and just DO it. Render a textured cube. Spin the cube based on arrow input. Render a heightmap. Render a cube on the heightmap that walks around based on arrow input. Make it jump with the space bar. Now you've essentially got the basis for a game, all you need is to import a model. Learn how to import models and get OpenGL to understand them.

If you're just having issues with Dev C++, then I would listen to what every one is telling you and **use something else**!. I think you can get a visual C++ express version for free, especially if you are a student at a University (most will have some sort of student MSDN subscription). Or as others have suggested, Code::Blocks is a great, free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider **Eclipse** as an option, I wrote an article about how to setup **Eclipse** to develop **OpenGL** (and **GLUT**) applications in **C/C++** and **Java** in both **Windows** and **Mac OS X**. This could be a starting point if you are interested.
It contains all the steps and all you need to know to have the system ready.

You can find it here:
[Setup Eclipse to develop OpenGL & GLUT apps in Java & C/C++ on Windows & MAC OS X!](http://riccardotramma.com/2011/04/setup-eclipse-to-develop-opengl-glut-apps-in-java-cc-on-windows-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about roughing it up. You'll be programming graphics which -with no implied modesty- is going to be rough enough without handicapping yourself.

Treat yourself and get Visual C++ is you're on windows.

If you want to get dirty, use only the OpenGL Core profile, and write your own shaders. Now that's a useful kind of dirty, and once you get past the brick wall learning curve, the world's your oyster.

Start with rendering the vertices as they appear. Later, you could write a geometry shader to render them as bezier points, as they were intended.